# Js insert in an initial text of the lines

Tags: javascript

I have the following function that works, but I wish I could write it more compactly.

```
function ymlComment(yml) {
  let ymlB = "/**\n* @swagger\n* definitions:\n";
  var lines = yml.split("\n").splice(1, yml.split("\n").length - 2);
  lines.forEach(function(el) {
    ymlB += "*" + el + "\n";
  });
  ymlB += "*/";
  return ymlB;
}
```

If you could also start from this, and insert the text between `definitions:\n` and `*/`, to do it even more compact would be great.

```
let ymlB = "/**\n* @swagger\n* definitions:\n*/";
```

Result:

```
/**
* @swagger
* ...
* ...
*/
```

Comment: @Code-Apprentice: I did not ask to write a code, I simply asked if there is a way to write the function that I have already written in a more compact and elegant way.

Comment: For review of working code, you should post at our sister site [CodeReview.SE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite it like this:

```
let ymlComment = yml => [
    '/**',
    '* @swagger',
    '* definitions:',
    ...yml.split("\n").slice(1, -1).map(x => '* ' + x),
    '*/'
].join('\n')
```

Of course, it should be ensured elsewhere that the `yml` param doesn't contain `*/`, which would break the generated code.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's actually not a huge difficulty. Inserting the description into a String Literal would do pretty much exactly what you're asking:

```js
// This function simply takes a string, and 
//  returns a string prepended with an asterisk
const defineLine = (el) => ` * ${el}`;

function ymlComment(yml) {
  // Split, same as you had in yours
  const lines = yml.split("\n").splice(1, yml.split("\n").length-2);
  // Using map, with the function above, we can 
  //   create an array of strings formatted as
  //   we like.
  const linesArr = lines.map(defineLine)

  // This is the fun bit - using a string literal,
  //  we can insert variables or operations into
  //  our string on the fly! Note the line
  // ${linesArr.join("\n")} - that's the insertion
  //  happening, and the strings being concatenated
  //  with a newline char.
  return `/**
 * @swagger
 * definitions
${linesArr.join("\n")}
 **/`
}

const yml = `first
second
third
fourth
fifth`;

console.log(ymlComment(yml) );
```